# how to display data from a database into two Textview

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

i'am trying develop an application which save points and date in a database but, i want to show into a list the points in green and date in white. The points and the time points are above one another. My code:
Class database
    public class BaseDeDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

```
public BaseDeDatos(Context context) {
    super(context, "puntuaciones", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE puntuaciones (puntos INTEGER,fecha VARCHAR)");

}
public void save(int points,String date){
     SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
     db.execSQL("INSERT INTO puntuaciones VALUES("+points+","+"'"+date+"')");
     db.close();
}
public Vector<String> listPoints(int cantidad) {
    Vector<String> result = new Vector<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT puntos, fecha FROM " +
    "puntuaciones ORDER BY puntos DESC LIMIT " +cantidad, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    result.add(cursor.getInt(0)+cursor.getString(1));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return result;
    }
```

and my class with the list

```
ListView lista;
BaseDeDatos bd;
Vector maxRegis;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maximos_registros);
    lista=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);
    lista.setBackgroundColor(color.Aquamarine);
    maxRegis= new Vector();
    bd= new BaseDeDatos(this);
    maxRegis=bd.listaPuntos(10);
    ArrayAdapter adaptador= new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.elemento_lista,R.id.tv1,maxRegis);
    //MyAdapter adaptador= new MyAdapter(this,bd);
    lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
}
```

and the code of R.layout.elemento_lista

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:textColor="#FFD700"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:text="" />
```

if i make a special adapter shows nothing, but with ArrayAdapter shows into the same TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `CustomAdapter` which `extends BaseAdapter`
Here is my sample [TodoApp](https://github.com/RediOne1/android-lab-4/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/androidlab4) with `CustomAdapter`.

You must inflate `R.layout.elemento_lista` in

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, null);
    }
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.todo_title);
    title.setText(getItem(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

Then find your `TextView` by id, setText, and that's all :-)

Comment: but....i use 2 TextView and i copied and pasted your code and the List shows points and date into the same TextView....

Comment: If you want, please send your adapter code on pastebin.com and paste link. It will be easier to help

Comment: It's shows same text in textViews, because you set same items as Text:
`tv1.setText(getItem(position).toString());
tv2.setText(getItem(position).toString());`
in previous adapter you setted Text like that:
`holder.texto.setText(vector.elementAt(position).toString().length()-19);
holder.texto2.setText(vector.elementAt(position).toString().substring(vector.elementAt(position).toString().length()-19, vector.elementAt(position).toString().length()));`

Comment: I guess you should set text this way:
`tv1.setText(getItem(position).toString().length()-19);
tv2.setText(getItem(position).toString().substring(getItem(position).toString().length()-19, getItem(position).toString().length()));`

Comment: oh! i understand, but the last error is in the: tv2.setText(getItem(position).toString().substring(getItem(position).toString().‌​length()-19, getItem(position).toString().length())); make error "sintax error, delete the these tokens"

Comment: StackOverflow's Markdown formatting added some invisible characters, between '.' and 'l' in `.length`, when you are copie and paste this line, so rewrite manually this line and it should work fine :)

Comment: perfect! Although the app doesn't works because it is not find a resource string in this lines "setText()..." doesn't matter xD